# New attribute is not working in magento

Tags: magento, attributes

I have created a new attribute Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes
COLOR in magento 
I have set its values ad Required, Visible, Searchable, comparable to yes

but it is not showing under my product.
Please help

Comment: First of all have you cleared cache? Reindex DB? Is your attribute not showing at front-end or back-end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the attribute to the attribute set for the relevant products?

Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Drews' answer have you reindexed the site: System > Index Management?

Comment: Why was this down voted? If you're going to down vote me at least have the courtesy to provide me with the reason why you feel it is a bad answer. That way we can all learn.

Comment: Agreed - this answer is no less useful that the accepted answer here.